# Nancy: Bind creates empty object

Tags: c#, nancy

This method does not work:

```
Post["/Login"] = action =>
{
    var options = this.Bind();
}
```

Variable "options" is empty! Object is not null, but it does not have any property filled.

```
Post["/Login"] = action =>
{
    RequestStream body = this.Request.Body;
    TextReader text = new StreamReader(body);
    JsonReader json = new JsonTextReader(text);

    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    dynamic options = serializer.Deserialize(json);
}
```

In second example "options" variable is OK... All properties are filled (not null).

I have figured out that internally Bind method will call the following code:

```
return (object) new DynamicModelBinderAdapter(module.ModelBinderLocator, module.Context, (object) null, configuration, blacklistedProperties);
```

But this adapter really is not the instance of object. It is just container for passed values. Also it has method TryConvert(ConvertBinder binder, out object result). Can anybody clarify what really Bind method makes? And is it possible to get desired behaviour (like it is in 2nd example).

Comment: Do you have an actual question?

Comment: JK, is it not clear that Bind does not work as expected?

Comment: Mark the question back... I need the answer and the question is really important... If you cannot help then don't kick the air.

Comment: Have you tried specifying the type of 'options'?

Comment: I expected that it can be a problem... So I tried to create type and use Bind<T>. But it did not work for me... And of course final goal is to get it in dynamic without many different types in project. For now as workaround I am using JsonConverter and custom implementation of Bind and JsonSerializer for dynamic.

Comment: @Maxim Nancy does not support binding to dynamic out of the box.

Comment: I guess now all is clear... Dynamic will not work without custom implementation of IModelBinder. Thanks Phill... I will investigate suggested solution. Also it will be good idea to add such functionality to NancyFX.

Comment: We have discussed it, it would probably come after vNext. But most people use concrete classes instead of dynamic so its low priority at the moment, sorry.